# “The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size…” error

Tags: file-uploads, size

I am trying to upload a 30MB PDF file. I keep getting the "“The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size…” error. I have turned off XSS filtering and here is my PHP info:

memory_limit    100M
post_max_size   12M
upload_max_filesize 80M
max_execution_time  300

I am a Super Admin. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your post_max_size needs to be at least 30MB to handle that file. It's set to 12M currently, which is not nearly enough. I generally set my post_max_size to be the same as upload_max_filesize just to keep things simple.

Comment: Oh geez. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!